# Empty wine desktop under linux?

Tags: linux, windows, desktop, wine

Using `wine` under `linux`, I want to start up a Windows desktop which doesn't run any program. I then want to interact with that desktop's `Start` menu, desktop icons, etc.

I know that I can run a specific Windows executable in a desktop by doing this ...

```
wine explorer /desktop some_executable.exe
```

However, if I leave `some_executable.exe` off, then the empty Windows desktop simply opens and then closes a few seconds later.

Is there any way to use `wine` to simply start an empty Windows desktop that remains on the screen?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize now that I can do the following:

- run `winecfg`, and under the "Graphics" tab, specify `Emulate a virtual desktop`
- then run `winetricks explorer`

This causes a virtual Windows desktop to be opened with `explorer` running. I can iconify `explorer`, and I can then run any wine-installed programs via that virtual Windows desktop.

This seems to be stable enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

[WINE](https://winehq.com) is not designed to create a stable Windows Desktop.

It provides a Linux system the limited ability to run some Windows-specific apps, but the Desktop is not one of them.

To do what you want, the well-accepted solution is to add desktop virtualization to your Linux system, using the Linux system as a virtualization host, *if* your hardware is capable (see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-xen-vmware-kvm-intel-vt-amd-v-support/ for details).

Do `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep lm` to confirm you have a 64-bit processor (required).

If so, then do `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -h "svm | vmx"` to see if that CPU is virtualization-capable.

There are [many virtualization host apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization).

Comment: Thank you. When I invoke `wine` with the `/desktop` option that I described above, it starts up a Windows desktop in which the application on the command line is opened. I think that I could get an apparently empty Windows desktop by writing a do-nothing Windows application which doesn't even open a window, installing it into my `wine` environment, and then starting it on the command line in place of `some_executable.exe` that I mentioned above. I guess that's the best I can do with `wine`. If I could get that to work, I'd rather do it that way than to go down the virtualization path.

Comment: I found a way to do what I want. See my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool that gives the start menu. Also, if you enable the desktop emulation in Wine, you'll get the taskbar when you use the Wine Start Menu Systray.exe app.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqfbu6gTBYg

The download is within the youtube description.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1149076)